# Can I use an if statement with a return value as a function argument in C?

Tags: c, function, pass-by-value

I want to be able to pass by value with an if statement:

```
 void function(int x){
      // do
 }
 int otherFunction1(){
      // do stuff
 }
 int otherFunction2(){
      // do other stuff
 }
 int main(){

      int x = 1;
      function(if (x==1)
                    return otherFunction1();
               else
                   return otherFunction2(); );

 }
```

Thanks for your time, and I am open to any other suggested approaches. I know I can accomplish this task by simply doing a bunch of if statements within the function itself. Was just curious if I could reduce the number of lines required.

Comment: Reducing the number of required lines is never an advantage, especially not if it decreases readability while not achieving any benefit.

Comment: `int rtnfunction(int x) {if (x == 1) return otherFunction1(); else return otherFunction2(); );` Then in `main()` call `return rtnfunction(x);`.

Comment: Or simply in `main()` so `return x == 1 ? otherFunction1() : otherFunction2();`

Comment: There is a way of achieving "less code"and minimal changes to your existing code. But it would get you in trouble with any teacher, friend, colleague or even yourself, when anybody tries to read your code in three weeks.

Comment: my bad, there should be an int parameter in function. I know it isn't necessarily good convention, and I would rarely use this, just on project I am working on now it would be convenient.

Comment: See `?` `:` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer with this construct which will surely get you in trouble.
I.e. I recommend to read this, see how horribly ugly it is and then NOT do it.

```
function((x==1)? otherFunction1() : otherFunction2() );
```

It uses the ternary operator `?:`. Which is used as `condition ? trueExpression : elseExpression`.

Please use this instead, though it is not as "short".

```
  if (x==1)
  { function( otherFunction1() ); }
  else
  { function( otherFunction2() ); }
```

Or use the proposal from the comment by David C. Rankin, especially if you end up doing this multiple times.

Comment: I appreciate this very much. Out of the thousands times I have had to do a problem like this, I would of course never use a conditional statement's return value to pass into a function, but it is convenient for me right now. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, the ternary alone in the function parameter list isn't bad, so long as you understand the functions already provide the return of the type of parameter required. It's probably not the recommended or most readable way, but it is certainly a "legal" way to do it.